# Not able to ping the biometric device "uface 800 ZKTeco" after power off

Tags: connection, biometrics, zkteco

I have recently bought uface 800 ZKTeco biometric devices and created the application to pull the attendance log from the device. Everything is working fine but whenever we are restarting machine by power off/on then I am not able to connect to the machine. I tried to ping the IP assigned to device from the command prompt but unable to ping, its saying "Request timed out.". I red the documentation provided with SDK but did not get any solution. Kingly help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: To be able to connect again, I need to reset the machine and assign the IP address again.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the DHCP in the biometric device and set the static ip. So that, after restarting the device, IP will not be changed automatically.

Comment: I have already disabled DHCP and after restarting device IP is not changing but still it's neither pinging nor I am able to connect from my application

Comment: Then how do you connect the device with your software with DHCP enabled?

Comment: No I am not connecting to the device with DHCP enabled. I am using static IP only. The problem is coming when i am switching off and on the device. Once I restart the machine then I have to 1)reset the machine, 2)Assign the same IP i used before. After doing this then i connects and works fine.

Comment: Looks like there is any issue in the firmware. Check with your vendor to update the firmware to fix the issue.